# Changing KML polygon color over time?

Tags: kml

I wrote a program that periodically outputs KML files.  These files contain a grid of polygons, always with the same  spatial coverage.  I want to use the polygon's fill color to represent a data values for each grid cell.  I know how to set the fill color of the polygon with the Style tag.  Is it possible to change to polygons color over time using the TimeStamp or TimeInterval?  If not, is there a way to hide an "old" polygon and draw a "new" polygon at the same location, but with a different color?  Is there a better way to represent a grid that has data value for each cell, like a Ground Overlay?

Comment: I think my answer below still stands - most of what you are asking requires programatic control over the UI (eg. the google map) do you have this? (I.e. is some third party loading you KML outside of your control, or are your users viewing it on your website? - as an example.) More details on what you are attempting to accomplish can help others provide a better answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For changing the polygon color, you need to use 3rd party kml parsers like geoxml3.
see this,
[changing the color of Polygons from KML rendered using geoxml3 on mouseover](https://code.google.com/p/geoxml3/)